# scanmem (Linux) vs. CheatEngine (Win)

Tags: linux, windows, memory, process, cheat-engine

`scanmem` is much slower than `CheatEngine` (although I run CheatEngine in my VirtualBox). Further scanmem is not able to scan for any-values (*) but CheatEngine is. How comes? Is there a better alternative for scanmem for Linux users?

Comment: Will cheat engine work under WINe?  I have this feeling it won't.  Have you tried?

Comment: I haven't. But this is a "dirty" alternative. I want to have it clean linux based. Besides it seems logical to me that you only can scan process which are started with wine if you use CheatEngine with wine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps give [Memscanner](http://code.google.com/p/memscanner/) a try? It hasn't had project updates since 2009, but it might be worth a shot.